# Why is my form just refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE: I have email-form as id and still have the same issue.

I have a form that when I submit, should pop-open and display a colorbox, but the code opens the colorbox, but in the blink of an eye, the page refreshes?

Here is my code:

```
            <html data-wf-page="546cd4ede4d" data-wf-site="5d0115c4ca7148">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Request Form</title>
          <meta content="Request a now." name="description">
          <meta content="Request Thingy" property="og:title">
          <meta content="Request a thingy now." property="og:description">
          <meta content="summary" name="twitter:card">
          <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
          <meta content="Webflow" name="generator">
          <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <link href="css/webflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <link href="css/sdfj.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            WebFont.load({
              google: {
                families: ["Ubuntu:300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic","Varela Round:400","PT Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic"]
              }
            });
          </script>
          <script src="js/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <link href="images/favicon2.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
          <link href="images/myfav.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

          <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-526-3'], ['_trackPageview']);
            (function() {
              var ga = document.createElement('script');
              ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
          </script>


          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://thingyss.com/css/colorbox.css" />

          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





        <style>
            #wrapper {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 1;
        }
        #wrapper input {
          padding-right: 14px;
        }
        #wrapper:after {
          content: "*";
          position: absolute;
          right: 15px;
          top: +12px;
          /*color: #ed9900;*/
          color: #39a2e2;
          z-index: 5;
        }





        </style>​


        </head>
        <body class="requestbody">

          <form id="email-form" name="email-form">
            ..........

            <div class="form_half_div right">
                          <div class="centered">
                            <input class="rounded_btn w-button w-preserve-3d" type="submit" value="Request Now" data-wait="Finding..." wait="Finding...">
                        </div>
                      </div>
           </form>


          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBpz8DQg&v=3.exp&libraries=places">
          </script>
          <script src="js/socket.io.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mystuff.js"></script>
          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
          <script src="js/autoNumeric.js"></script>
          <script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

            <script>


          $(document).ready(function() {
            setTypes();
            initialize();

            $("#email-form").submit(function(){
              requestTruckWarning(); // creates a colorbox
              e.preventDefault(); // trying to prevent page from refreshing but never hits this breakpoint?
              return false;
            });
            document.onkeypress = stopReturnKey;
          });

          function initialize() {

            var options = {
              types: ['(cities)'],
              componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
             };


            var mapOptions = {
              center: { lat: 39.707187, lng: -100.722656},
              zoom: 14,
              draggable: false,
              scrollwheel: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
              map.setOptions({draggable: true});
            });

            bootstrapHome(map);

          }

          function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
                    geolocation));
              });
            }
          }




          </script>

         <!--  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> -->
        <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
          <!-- [if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif] -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I don't see the id `email-form` anywhere.

Comment: @jdog: after updating the `id`, did you add the parameter `e` to your callback function as described below? That should fix your error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forget to pass the event variable `e` as parameter to submit callback:

```
       $("#email-form").submit(function(e){ //Here
          requestTruckWarning(); // creates a colorbox
          e.preventDefault(); // trying to prevent page from refreshing but   never hits this breakpoint?
        });
```

Comment: return false should do if not passed the param.

Answer (score 3):

In your callback function, you're missing the passed parameter `e` (the event object):

```
$('#email-form').submit(function (e) {
    requestTruckWarning() // Creates a colorbox
    e.preventDefault() // This now works, because `e` exists
})
```

Additionally, it looks like some other answers (credit to [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41044846/7256039)) have pointed out that `#email-form` does not refer to an element in your document. That must be fixed before the above code will run successfully.

Comment: return false should do if not passed the param.

Comment: Correct, that would be redundant. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

Your `form` does not have any ID named `#email-form`. Either add the ID attribute:

```
<form id='#email-form'>
```

or change the selector:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
```

---

and as other answers are also mentioned you have to pass `e` as event in the submit callback.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ // <-------here
```

***Yet other two changes has to be done as suggest above.***

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two problems here. As @Jai said, you do no have an id attribute set for the form, so jQuery is looking for the element with id='email-form', and finding nothing, so the code doesn't execute. Even if it did execute, it wouldn't stop the form submit, because while you are using e.preventDefault, the 'e' in this case is the event object, which is a thing that you need to have passed in to your event handler. Add the id to your for, then change the declaration for your event handler like so:

```
        $("#email-form").submit(function(e){
```